# C# Random() isn't working very randomly

Tags: c#, random, xna

Quick question guys

In my game, I currently have to items which spawn at the bottom of the screen and move upwards. Once they reach the top of the screen or collide with the player they despawn and are supposed to spawn at a random point along the X axis at the bottom of the screen. The first item always seems to spawn at a random point, however, the second object always seems to spawn at the same point as the first, despite being spawning using a separate call of the method. Any ideas? Here's the code I'm using:

```
       public void ReSpawn()

        this.RandX = this.random.Next(30, 650);
        this.Position.X = RandX;
        this.Position.Y = 710;

        if (Object1.Position.Y <= -25) //If item reaches top of screen

                Object1.ReSpawn(); 

        if (Object1.rectangle.Intersects(Player.rectangle)) //Collision with player


                Object1.ReSpawn(); 

        if (Object2.Position.Y <= -25) //If item reaches top of screen

                Object2.ReSpawn();

        if (Object2.rectangle.Intersects(Player.rectangle)) //Collision with player


                Object1.ReSpawn();
```

Declared using:

```
    public Random random = new Random();
    public int RandX;
```

Comment: Where and how are you declaring your `Random` object?

Comment: How did you instantiate your variable random?

Comment: What monster ate your brackets?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add delcaration, just edited it in now

Comment: And it was delcared right at the start of the class, before any methods etc.

Comment: @AJCol Where it is (relative to other class members) isn't really relevant...

Comment: @AJCol, if you are reinstantiating your class repeatedly, say in a loop or just in a pair of consecutive executions of code, you're going to instantiate your random with a same seed which would trigger repetitive values. Your description and code so far indicates this could be happening, but we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two objects are probably not sharing a `Random` object.  So both objects are going to generate the same sequence of random numbers.

Share a `Random` object between the two objects and they should generate different values.

**Edit:**

Make `random` static so all objects use it.

```
public static Random random = new Random();
```

Comment: This is correct. The default constructor for Random uses the current time for the seed. So, if two Random objects are instantiated at the same time, they will produce the same random sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeding your random number generator

```
    Random rand1 = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx

Comment: Seeding won't help. The random instance is seeded by default based on the current time, and the thinking is that the problem is the OP is likely getting multiple instances at the same time as it is.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want a good random number generator, I recommend `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` instead of just `Random`. Not sure if it impacts performance, however.

Comment: Might need to do a bit more research before you answer this, `Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` is much slower than `Random`

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't sure if it impacted performance. But if you _do_ want a better RNG at the cost of speed (for, say, level generation or item placement), I don't see anything wrong with my answer.

Comment: Well that was my point, I would think you would check for yourself before answering.

Comment: I'm not sure that "cryptographically secure" really maps to "better" for the purposes of game development, performance issues aside.  Is there really any benefit to making your level generation unpredictable in principle instead of just unpredictable in practice?

Comment: Not really, but it's another way to do random number generation. I find it more 'random' than normal Random.